# Javascript dynamically inserted later on: how to make it run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have scripts In my React app that are inserted dynamically later on. The scripts don't load.

In my database there is a field called `content`, which contains data that includes html and javascript. There are many records and each record can include multiple scripts in the `content` field. So it's not really an option to statically specify each of the script-urls in my React app. The field for a record could for example look like:

```
<p>Some text and html</p>
<div id="xxx_hype_container">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://example.com/uploads/hype_generated_script.js?499892"></script>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"> 
<div>Some text.</div> 
Etc…
```

I call on this field in my React app using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div data-page="clarifies">
            <div className="container">
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />
                ... some other data
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It correctly loads the data from the database and displays the html from that data. However, the Javascript does not get executed. I think the script doesn't work because it is dynamically inserted later on. **How can I make these scripts work/run?**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20584396) suggest a solution for dynamically inserted scripts, but I don't think I can apply this solution because in my case the script/code is inserted from a database (so how to then use `nodeScriptReplace` on the code...?). Any suggestions how I might make my scripts work?

---

**Update** in response to @lissettdm their answer:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.ref = React.createRef();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.postData !== this.props.postData) {
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            post: this.props.postData.data,
            //etc
        });
        setTimeout(() => parseElements());

        console.log(this.props.postData.data.content);
        // returns html string like: `<div id="hype_container" style="margin: auto; etc.`
        const node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.props.postData.data.content);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.ref));
        // returns {"current":null}
        console.log(node);
        // returns [object DocumentFragment]
        this.ref.current.appendChild(node);
        // produces error "Cannot read properties of null"
    }
}

render() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    /etc.
    return (
        {loading ? (
            some code
        ) : (
            <div data-page="clarifies">
                <div className="container">
                    <div ref={this.ref}></div>
                    ... some other data
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    );
}
```

The `this.ref.current.appendChild(node);` line produces the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your are sure about HTML string content is safety and contains a string with valid HTML you can use [Range.createContextualFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) (executes scripts )

```
function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    /* convert your HTML string into DocumentFragment*/
    const node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(HTML);
    ref.current.appendChild(node);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HTML String</h1>
      <div>
        <div ref={ref}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See how `script` content is executed on JavaScript console [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fx79m8)

If your are using `class component` create `ref` within class constructor, then update node content, I did it in `componentDidMount` just for testing:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(HTML);
    this.ref.current.appendChild(node);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>HTML String</h1>
        <div>
          <div ref={this.ref}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

see this [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sn8ysq)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to tweak this to my use case and have added an update to my post about this.

Comment: Hi @Nick with class component is a little bit different, I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again @lissettdm! I've updated my update to show the error it produces with my implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick why do you need to use `JSON.stringify(node)`?  that will returns null because node is typeof DocumentFragment, you just need to append it to the div. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the `JSON.stringify`. The `console.log(node);` then returns `[object DocumentFragment]`. I've added the error I get to the OP.

Comment: did you add ref to the node? `<div ref={this.ref}></div>`, seems like you are missing that..if not, its possible that the node is not mounted in DOM

Comment: Yes, I did add that (I've expanded my OP a bit on this). Not completely sure what "node is not mounted in DOM" means. Without `post.content` the page loads/displays correctly. Perhaps it's the `loading` part (see OP)... I mean, that does not include `<div ref={this.ref}></div>` because there I don't want to display it.

Comment: Yes, if I also add the line `<div ref={this.ref}></div>` inside the part where `loading` is `true`, then the error is gone. It doesn't display my html on the page though, but I think that's a separate issue, since your working example works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nick that makes sense, if loading true `<div ref={this.ref}></div>` won't be rendered, so you need to apply your logic in `setState` callback `this.setState({
            loading: false,
            post: this.props.postData.data,
            //etc
        }, () => { /*update node content here*/});`

Comment: Yes, now it works perfectly and displays the html!

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this. You may create a function that can be called on to dynamically create and inject the `<script>` tag into the `<body>` of the React application.

```
const addScript = () => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = '<url-of-the-script>';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = function() {
        // Do something
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

You may call this `addScript` function when the required component loads using the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    addScript();
    return () => {
        // remove the script on component unmount
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: But for this to work you need to know the script url, right? These url's are not known in advance; there are many in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering raw HTML without React recommended method is not a good practice. React recommends method  dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render raw HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I used the following on my React page: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }} />`. Unfortunately, the result was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first fetch the dynamic data from the db using a fetch call and make use of useEffect, Inside which after the data is fetched you set it to a useState hook variable which will hold the data for this.

```
const [dbData,setDbData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  const dbReqFunc = async () => {
    // req your dynamic data here and set the data fetched to dbData
    // using setDbData(...)
  };

  dbReqFunc();
},[]);  // Making the call on component loading (Modify accordingly based on 
        // needs)
```

After this once the data has been set you can make use of another useEffect hook which should be below the previous useEffect hook. Then you can call your function for the entire dynamic URL fetched and append it to the HTML document ( I have attached all the scripts to a div for easy cleanup).

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(dbData.length>0){
    const elem = document.createElement('div');
    dbData.map(data=> {

        // based on data returned modify accordingly

        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = '...script-url...';
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = function() {
          // Do something
        };
     
        //...other script fields...       

        elem.appendChild(script);
      });
     
     // attach elem to body
     document.body.appendChild(elem);

     return ()=>{
      // clean-up function
        document.body.removeChild(elem);
     };
  }

},[dbData]);
```

This should load the script data and should load the scripts.

NOTE: Make sure you are putting the the dynamic db call for fetching the data before the 2nd useEffect. So, that it runs in order.